# How to get Local development STS running

Tags: security, wif

I am in need of help getting Local Development STS running. I just started with MSDN tutorials and got stuck when trying to build WCF service using WIF. So far I did following:

1. Installed "Identity and Access Tools" in my Visual Studio 2012
2. Created new WCF Service project in new solution
3. Right clicked projects name and selected "Identity and access..."
4. Selected "Use the Local Development STS" option on first tab and changed token
   type to "SAML 2.0" on "Local Development STS" tab
5. Clicked "Ok"

I end up with following that informs me about problems with certificate:

[image: Identity and Access dialog]

- I verified that the file is there physically.
- I verified access to it - System, Administrators and my user have full access to it (only last option is unchecked)
- I tried to install the certificate manually, but it is protected with password and I cant find it anywhere
- I tried to toy around with "Identity and Access..." wizard
- I tried to google the answer
- I tried to check if I have certificate like that installed, there are tree Personal certificates in my Local Machine store, but I have no idea how to check their subject or whatever else

So far I wasn't successful. Could anyone advise how to fix the situation, so I can be sure I have proper certificate installed, I would be eternally grateful.

Erchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the .NET 4.5 tutorials - [WIF Code Sample Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545413.aspx)?

To check the subject:

Start / Run / mmc

File / Add - Remove Snap In

Certificates - Add.

My User Account - Finish - OK

Expand the tree as required - double click on certificate - Details.

Comment: I am using this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545447.aspx I was this far already with certificates, I just dont know which atribute is the one I am looking for (no "CN=something" value there)

Comment: If you click on the subject, you'' see "CN=xxx" in the details box.

Comment: Thanks, thats it - I have one certficate already with proper subject. Thanks for help.